# Duplicate List<T>.Add(T item) Items

Tags: c#, list

Why does `aFooList` contain five copies of the last item, instead of the five items I inserted?

Expected Output: `01234`

Actual Output: `44444`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace myTestConsole {
    public class foo {
        public int bar;
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            foo aFoo = new foo(); // Make a foo
            List<foo> aFooList = new List<foo>(); // Make a foo list

            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) { 
                aFoo.bar = i;
                aFooList.Add(aFoo);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                Console.Write(aFooList[i].bar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only creating a foo object once, and adding it to the list 5 times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added the same item, `aFoo`, 5 times. When you modify contents of a reference-type object you don't create new copies, you modify the same object.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<foo> aFooList = new List<foo>(); // Make a foo list

for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) { 
    foo aFoo = new foo(); // Make a foo
    aFoo.bar = i;
    aFooList.Add(aFoo);
}
```

You are still modifying your aFoo while it is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable 'aFoo' is basically a pointer to a location in memory.  Without "newing" up another instance (malloc) you're modifying the same location in memory and add the same pointer 5 times.

The "new" keyword fullfills the function as far as programmers are concerned in C# as malloc does in C.  It will get a new memory location and make aFoo point to that location, instead of the old one.

From MSDN:

```
The new operator is used to create objects and invoke constructors
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newoperator)

Answer (score 0):

You've added a reference to the same object to your list 5 times, each time modify the value of `bar`.  Add this line after `aFooList.Add(aFoo);` to see the effect each time you add a `foo` to the list.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", foos.Select(f => f.bar)));
```

For what it's worth, it's a one-liner (spaced nicely for readability) with Linq.

```
var foos = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
                     .Select(n => new foo {bar = n})
                     .ToList();
```

---

Complete example:

```
foo aFoo = new foo(); // Make a foo
List<foo> aFooList = new List<foo>(); // Make a foo list
Console.WriteLine("\nUsing aFooList");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    aFoo.bar = i;
    aFooList.Add(aFoo);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", aFooList.Select(f => f.bar)));
}

var foos = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(n => new foo { bar = n }).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("\nUsing foos");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", foos.Select(f => f.bar)));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
Using aFooList
0
11
222
3333
44444

Using foos
01234
```